# Kivy - How to read a CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, kivy

After looking all over google i didn't find a way of accessing my CSV file while executing the application on android.

There's a function in my code that does that:

```
def set_dataset(self):
    cgpb = pd.read_csv('canais_cgepb.csv', decimal=',')

    # Realizando o print do DataFrame
    self.dataset = cgpb
```

But when i execute my application that's what i got (from Android Log):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File canais_cgepb.csv does not exist: 'canais_cgepb.csv'
```

I'm compiling the apk with all content of the project in the same directory.

Comment: is it possible to print ` os.getcwd()` in the log to debug it or `os.listdir()` ? so you know that file path is making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the inbuilt `csv` package([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) to read the csv file?

If you can open any other file in your app then you should be able to read this csv file too.

example:

```
open("anais_cgepb.csv", "w") as file:

    csv_file = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")

    for line in csv_file:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's like the file (.csv) isn't imported to the APK while compiled, so when the function calls it, whether using pandas or not, the file isn't found (FileNotFoundError).

Comment: @culpinha in that case I would try test importing files and figure out a solution. It might be related to the path of the file.